# Automation Error System Call Failed - Outlook and Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

Quite stumped here. Getting Run-Time Error -2147417856 (80010100) Automation Error System Call Failed

I have a couple outlook rules that run a scripts.

The first Outlook script opens an excel file and runs the macros in the excel file and repeats this two time (as seen below). Then the Outlook script closes Excel and exits the sub. The error occurs while in the second Excel file's macros.

```
'First File

Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

xlApp.Visible = False

xlApp.Application.DisplayAlerts = False

xlApp.Application.EnableEvents = False

Set xlWork = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(strPath & "\File1.xlsm")

xlWork.Application.Run "Macro1_Module.Macro1"

xlWork.Application.Run "Macro2_Module.Macro2"

xlWork.SaveAs FileName:=savepath1, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook

xlWork.Close

Set xlWork = Nothing

xlApp.Application.DisplayAlerts = True

xlApp.Application.EnableEvents = True

xlApp.Quit

Set xlApp = Nothing

'Second File

Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

xlApp.Visible = False

xlApp.Application.DisplayAlerts = False

xlApp.Application.EnableEvents = False

Set xlWork = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(strPath & "\File2.xlsm")

xlWork.Application.Run "Macro1_Module.Macro1"

xlWork.Application.Run "Macro2_Module.Macro2"

xlWork.SaveAs FileName:=savepath2, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook

xlWork.Close

Set xlWork = Nothing

xlApp.Application.DisplayAlerts = True

xlApp.Application.EnableEvents = True

xlApp.Quit

Set xlApp = Nothing
```

The macros in the excel file create an email using data in Excel and sends it via Outlook (CreateObject("Outlook.Application")). This uses the below code to generate the email.

```
Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

OutApp.Session.Logon

Set Outmail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

On Error Resume Next

With Outmail

.To = ""

.CC = ""

.BCC = ""

.Subject = "Test"

.HTMLBody = "TEST"

.Attachments.Add (ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & ActiveWorkbook.Name)

End With

Outmail.Display

On Error GoTo 0

Set Outmail = Nothing

Set OutApp = Nothing
```

The second Outlook script can sometime get triggered while the first is running. I thought that the rules created a backlog and ran one after another. When the first script is running in Outlook then Excel, it errors after the second email comes in to trigger the second Outlook script (similar to the first but opens a different file). The below error message occurs while the first script is running through the Excel macros (in second file) and when you Debug, it highlights

```
Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
```

This error doesn't happen when these two email triggered Outlook scripts are spaced out enough to let everything finish. So I know that the two scripts work when separately run (and I have tested this).

Does anyone have any idea what could be causing this to happen? Can two email rules that trigger scripts run simultaneously if one of them is currently working in Excel?

[image]

Comment: Nice picture, can you add that the error code to your question- also don't `CreateObject` cuz Outlook is already running so `GetObject` that's running or set your outapp to `New Outlook.Application` make sure to reference Outlook library

Comment: @0m3r Thanks! I added the error code to the question. If I have VBA running in outlook (via rule) and I run a macro in Excel that uses 'GetObject' to create an email (and send), will there be any issues since Outlook VBA is running at the same time?

Comment: I mean the code you posted as picture needs to be added your question so we can copy/paste to run a test-

Comment: @0m3r Ah gotcha, just added it

Comment: @0m3r - absolutely not. CreateObject must always be used - Outlook is a singleton, so if it is already running, CreateObject will return a pointer to the already running instance. If it is not running, Outlook will be started.

Comment: Your correct- I was mixing up the Single-Use & Multi-Use Applications

Answer (score 0):

The error is RPC_E_SYS_CALL_FAILED, which most likely means Outlook is running i na different security context. Make sure they are the same and neither app is running with elevated privileges as administrator.

Comment: Thanks for the response! When I pull up task manager, both Outlook and Excel are "Disabled" under the UAC Virtualization column. Doesn't this show whether apps are running with elevated privileges?

Comment: I don't know. How were both apps started?

Comment: Outlook was currently running (I opened it manually), the email comes in, triggers the rule that runs the Outlook script which opens Excel via `CreateObject("Excel.Application")`. The script then runs the Excel VBA that uses `CreateObject("Outlook.Application")` to get the current Outlook to create an email. This process works perfectly as long as the other email (2nd script via Outlook rule) doesn't come in while the first script is running from what I can tell.

Comment: That makes sense - if the COM system is in the out-bound inter-proc call, another RPC call can fail.

Comment: Do you know a way around this? Is there a way I can check to see if there is currently a call then wait if there is? I am not very knowledgeable in this so I don't fully understand how this works. Any insight would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I think there is a way to do that using VBA. Why not do all the work in your Outlook script? Or at least not run it when you open the file?

Comment: I guess I could do all the Excel manipulation in the Outlook script, it was just easier to run the already existing macros in Excel. The idea was to allow emails to come in that trigger the generation of a new report that is sent out using data in the email (or attachment) without user intervention. If you can think of a way to get around this in the VBA, please let me know!